# how would you translate 在我找到工作之前 ? What is the function of 在 here?

Tags: grammar

I don't understand what 在 means here?

Answer (score 2):

[.....] 之前 = before [.....]

[我找到工作] 之前 = before [I found a job]

~

在 [.....] 之前 = at before [.....]

[**在** (我找到工作) 之前] = [**at** (the time) before (我找到工作) ]

在我找到工作之前 = At the time before I found a job

Answer (score 1):

You're probably familiar with 在 meaning "at" with regards to a location, you probably just haven't yet recognized that it can also mean "at" with regards to a time (i.e "at that time"). Treat it as the equivalent of "when" in English. Where in English we would say "When I found work", in Chinese you would say "我找到工作的时候" (the time that I found work) or "在我找到工作" (at (when) I found work).

The 之前 means before. In this context imagine there's a 的 in the sentence:

在我找到工作(的)之前 ([when I found work]'s before)

Taken as a whole, the phrase means "before I found work...".

Comment: How about "在我学习的同时...." Is it similar in that sense? How about we simply omit 在？ Would the sentences hold the same meaning and would they then be grammatically correct?